# Editable JTable Tutorial

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Are there any good books or website that go over creating a `JTable`? I want to make one column editable.  I would like to actually put a inherited `JCheckBox` component (that we created here) into one of the table columns instead of just having the table put `JCheckBox` in based on it being an editable `boolean` field.

I have the [JFC Swing Tutorial Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201914670) book but I just would like to know if there are other examples I could look at and learn how to deal with the tables better.  The book seems to just take the java 'trail' online and put it in the book.

I am re-reading the stuff though, just curious if anyone has found something that might help out more.

Comment: Please rephrase the question, so that it doesn't sound off-topic ("Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.").

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To make a column editable you have to override the `isCellEditable` method in the `TableModel`. Creating a `TableModel` is fairly easy if you inherit `AbstractTableModel` and I'd recommend it for all but the most simple `JTable`s.

However, adapting the `TableModel` is only part of what you need to do. To actually get a custom component in the `JTable`, you need to set a custom cell renderer. To use an interactive custom component, you need to set a custom cell editor. In some cases, it's enough to use slightly modificated versions of the default classes for this.

**Editors**

If you already have got a custom component is easily done using delegation: Create a new class implementing `TableCellEditor`, and return a **new** instance of the component in the `getCellEditorComponent` method. The paramaters to this method include the current value as well as the cell coordinates, a link back to the table and wether or not the cell is selected.

The `TableCellEditor` also has a method that is called when the user commits a change to the cell contents (where you can validate user input and adjust the model) or cancels an edit. Be sure to call the `stopEditing()` method on your editor if you ever programmatically abort editing, otherwise the editor component will remain on screen -- this once took me like 2 hours to debug.

Note that within a `JTable` editors and **only** editors receive events! Displaying a button can be done using a renderer. But to get a functioning button, you need to implement an editor with the correct `EventListeners` registered. Registering a listener on a renderer does nothing.

**Renderers**

Implementing a renderer is not strictly necessary for what you describe in your question, but you typically end up doing it anyway, if only for minor modifications. Renderers, unlike editors, are speed critical. *The `getTableCellRendererComponent` of a renderer is called once for every cell in the table!* The component returned by a renderer is only used to paint the cell, not for interaction, and thus can be "reused" for the next cell. In other words, you should adjust the component (e.g. using `setText(...)` or `setFont(...)` if it is a `TextComponent`) in the renderer, you should *not* instantiate a new one -- that's an easy way to cripple the performance.

**Caveats**

Note that for renderers and editors to work, you need to tell the `JTable` when to use a certain renderer/editor. There are basically two ways to do this. You can set the default cell renderer/editor **for a certain type** using the respective `JTable` methods. For this way to work, your `TableModel` needs to return exactly this type in the `getColumnClass(...)` method! The default table model will **not** do this for you, it always returns `Object.class`. I'm sure that one has stumped a lot of people.

The other way to set the editor/renderer is by explicitly setting it on the column itself, that is, by getting the `TableColumn` via the `getTableColumn(...)` method of the `JTable`. This is a lot more elaborate, however, it's also the only way to have two different renderers/editors for a single class. E.g. your model might have two columns of class String which are rendered in entirely different ways, maybe once using a `JLabel/DefaultRenderer` and the other using a `JButton` to access a more elaborate editor.

`JTable` with its custom renderers and editors is *extremely* versatile, but it is also a lot to take in, and there are a lot of things to do wrong. Good luck!

[How to Use Tables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) in [The Swing Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) is mandatory reading for anyone customising JTables. In particular, read and reread [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) because it typically takes a while for it to "click". The examples on custom renderers and editors are also very worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

The class you want to look into extending to create your own behavior is DefaultTableModel.  That will allow you to define your own behavior.  A decent tutorial can be found [on sun's site](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Comment: yeah, thats the trail I am currently looking at :)  We have extended AbstractTableModel here before and I know I have to override getColumnClass & isCellEditable and all that, I am just having trouble grasping dealing with all this on editable cells :(

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial from the [java lobby](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/jtable/) is easy to follow.  The online [Swing trail for JTable](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) that you reference indicates that it has been updated.  Did you scan through the whole thing for possible better (isn't newer always better) information?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use a simple `JTable` with 1 column editable and you know the column location you could always use default table model and overload the `isCellEditable` call.

something like this :

```
myTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(){
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    if (column == x) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
});
```

And for the check box create a renderer class

```
MyCheckBoxRenderer extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer
```

Answer (score 0):

Some useful classes are:

`Package javax.swing.table` :

`TableModel` - Interface for a `tablemodel`
`AbstractTableModel` - Nice class to extend for creating your own table with custom data structures
`DefaultTableModel` - Default table model which can deal with `arrays[]` and `Vectors`

To disable editing on any cell you need to override the `isCellEditable(int row, int col)` method

Answer (score 0):

in your table Model, you should override "isCellEditable" and "setValueAt" functions, like below.
Column 4 is the column for editable cells.

Then when you double click the cell and type something,
setValueAt() will be called and save the value to the tableModel's DO,field col4.

```
public ArrayList<XXXDO> tbmData = new ArrayList<XXXDO>(); //arraylist for data in table

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    if (col == 4) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    if ((row >= 0) && (row < this.tbmData.size()) && (col >= 0) && (col < this.colNm.length)) {
        if (col == 4) {
            tbmData.get(row).col4= (String) value;
        }
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    } else {
    }
}
```