# editing jtable - java

Tags: java, jtable, edit

I have a jTable which displays data from a database.
The user can edit these data, and when he presses on the "save" button, the new values should be saved in the database through an "update" query.

The problem is that when the user edits a certain cell, I use :

```
 newValue = model.getValueAt(row,column) ...
```

I still get the older value and not the new edited one.
What could be the cause of this error ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you should call `((DefaultCellEditor)table.getCellEditor()).stopCellEditing();` before calling `getValueAt` but I'm not sure.

Comment: It worked only for the first row, when i try to access the second row I get a nullpointerexception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85046/editable-jtable-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

See [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for the cause and solution of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would call model.fireTableDataChanged()